# How do I iterate over PSObject in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

From my C# code, I'm calling a PowerShell file. This PowerShell file calls an API like this:

```
$tickets = Invoke-RestMethod -uri 'x'

return $tickets.value
```

From my C# code, I'm storing the returned result in a variable like this:

```
var tickets = pipeline.Invoke();

foreach (var ticket in tickets)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ticket.Status); //ERROR
}
```

I'm getting an error here saying that `foreach` cannot operate on variables of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.

Printing 'tickets' returns this:

> @{Id=581; CID=3; Status=Active}
>
> @{Id=545; CID=6; Status=Active}

I need to be able to iterate through each ticket in tickets.

Comment: You only need **1** `foreach` in C# - you don't need to do what you just did in PowerShell again

Comment: @mathias: please check the new edits in the OP

Comment: var tickets, what type is tickets, you may need to convert to an enumabrable type

Comment: @saj its PSObject type. how do I make it enumerable?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ticket.Properties["Status"].Value);
```